# Determining stale connections in signalr

Tags: signalr

There are many articles showing how to do your own advanced connection handling with SignalR like [this blog post about "Mapping ASP.NET SignalR Connections to Real Application Users"](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/mapping-asp-net-signalr-connections-to-real-application-users).

All these solutions rely on the the OnDisconnect event:

```
public override Task OnDisconnected()
{
    SignalRConnectionManager.RemoveConnection(Context.ConnectionId);
    return base.OnDisconnected();
}
```

This works as long as you can rely on the OnDisconnected event. If your application crashes/restarts or server restarts then you won't get a OnDisconnected event for each connection.

Question: I have the connection in my database. I know that many of those connections are stale. Is there a possibility in SignalR to find out if a connection is stale? I tried

```
Clients.Client[StaleConnectionId]
```

hoping for null or an exception in case of an invalid connection ID.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is no way to check for a "Stale" connection.  I'm assuming your trouble lies in persisting a users state in some fashion and you want to know when to expire them.

SignalR has fail safes to expire connections based on idle activity so I'd recommend building in an idle feature into your applications logic through which you can expire users.

I've implemented this logic in [ShootR](http://shootr.signalr.net) (https://github.com/NTaylorMullen/ShootR) in case you want to have a basis to work off of.

Hope this helps!

Comment: OK, I also implemented some safeguards. I had hoped to find a cleaner solution...

Comment: @N. Taylor Mullen, could you let me know exactly where the logic is?

Comment: What logic are you referring to?  The logic in ShootR?

Comment: yes the logic in ShootR. Actually a bigger question I have is that let's suppose we have N clustered signalR servers (e.g., common Cloud environment) In this case, is there any way to figure our the state of a given channel? (i.e., whether a given connection is connected or disconnected)

Comment: In ShootR the user management is handled via the UserHandler.cs class.  It doesn't add users on OnConnected though, instead it waits for the client to initialize a user by calling a server method.  Now to your next question, the SignalR scale-out story has not been finalized yet so i'll have to give you a rain check.